# NAU8822 I2S Codec + ESP32 - no valid data

Tags: codec, arduino-esp32, i2s

I've connected a NAU8822 codec to an ESP32 and I'm trying to record audio from a microphone.

[schematic of NAU8822 circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRdDX.png)

Following setup:

- Microphone is biased (working), mono
- Codec works as I2S master (working)
- MCLK is generated by ESP32 (working)
- ESP32 is I2S slave and receiving data
- standard I2S, 16bit @ 16kHz

Clocks:

- MCLK is 4.096MHz, as required (256*f_sample)
- WS/FS is 16kHz
- BCLK is 512kHz (f_sample * 2 * 16bit)

The problem is:

I receive either 0 or 65535, there is no other value.
The I2S data line doesn't show any signs of a frequency higher than 16kHz on the scope, I expect data with BCLK, not WS frequency.

On the scope, there is a clearly visible connection between sound and the pulse **density**,
the signal looks more like a slow PDM modulated signal, not the required PCM. The NAU datasheet has no signs whatsoever of having a PDM output.

Are there any hints what could have gone wrong in this case?

I tried using different sample rates, always the same result.
I tried using a different BCLK prescaler in the NAU, same result
Disabling / enabling different gain control settings also have no impact.